# Picard Theorem globally Lipschitz

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I understand the proof apart from the last step which I have highlighted in green.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the previous step, you show

$$|P(x)(t) - P(y)(t)| \leq \frac{1}{2}\|x - y\|$$

so

\begin{align*}
\|P(x) - P(y)\| &= \max_{t\in[-h,h]}|(P(x) - P(y))(t)|\\ 
&= \max_{t\in[-h,h]}|P(x)(t) - P(y)(t)|\\ 
&\leq \max_{t\in[-h,h]}\frac{1}{2}\|x - y\|\\
&= \frac{1}{2}\|x-y\|.
\end{align*}